# Missing contamination delay specification for a component

Tags: delay, timing-analysis, sequential-logic

If IIUC: contamination delay (\$t_{cd}\$) is the time where the signal level on the output of a component starts to change in response to a change on the component's input, while the propagation delay (\$t_{pd}\$) is where this signal level change on the output stabilizes (i.e. becomes valid). Furthermore  \$t_{cd,min}\$ of a component must be bigger than the maximum hold time of a subsequent component connected to the first component's output.

While all component specifications I found provide \$t_{pd,max}\$ none of them provided \$t_{cd,min}\$. What is the reason for this? Can I assume in this case that \$t_{cd,min} = t_{pd,max}\$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but \$t_{pd(min)}\$ is the same thing as your \$t_{cd(min)}\$.

I never understood why people felt the need to create a new term for it.

Comment: And if the minimum propagation delay is not specified, assume that it is zero.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense that we can assume that \$t_{cd(min)}\$ is \$t_{pd(min)}\$ or 0 if the latter is not specified.

I'd like to note that there seems to be a valid reason for differentiating between \$t_{cd}\$ and \$t_{pd}\$. The former would mark the delay where the output signal level becomes _invalid_ (used to check against hold time violations), while the latter marks the delay where the output signal level becomes _valid_ (used to check against setup time violations). The min,typ,max values would just mark the min,typ,max delays for each of these _distinct_ events.

Comment: I understand the distinction you're making, but in practical terms, there's no real use for \$t_{pd(min)}\$ other than to mean the same thing as \$t_{cd(min)}\$ -- you can't base your design on the *earliest* time a signal might become valid. Therefore, it has always been understood that the minimum propagation delay means the exact same thing as "output hold time" -- what you're calling "contamination delay".